# trouble getting a latitude longitude to cartesian converter to work

Tags: javascript, three.js, exif, cartesian-coordinates

My project geo locates geometry according to two separate geo-tagged photos (  *using the library [lon_lat_to_cartesian](https://gist.github.com/nicoptere/2f2571db4b454bb18cd9)* ) the first representing viewer, the second the geometry. The latter of the two causes the problems.

Lat' long' data is passed from the exif reader, and successfully converted into a cartesian vector(for the first photo):

```
$("#imageInput").change(function() {
        readBackgroundFile(this);
        readExif(this, function(Data) {
            resizeViewport(data.width, data.height);
            position =lonLatToVector3(data.latitude, data.longitude);
                console.log(position);
            rotation = data.rotation;
            updateScenePlacement(position, rotation, "viewer");
        });
    });
```

console log:

```
Object { x: 0.30023741043429497, y: 0.9038698398763119, z:     -0.3047569686449829 } glMain.js:153:5
```

As for the second photo, Lat' long' data is still passed from the exif reader, but unfortunately not converted into a cartesian vector, until line 153:5 where the console outputs unusually small values:

```
$("#exifInput").change(function() {
        readExif(this, function(data) {
            position =lonLatToVector3(data.latitude, data.longitude);
                console.log(position);
            rotation = data.rotation;
            updateScenePlacement(position, rotation, "placement");
        });
    });
```

console log:

```
52.62939166666667 glMain.js:183:5
1.1289861111111112 glMain.js:186:5
Object { x: NaN, y: 0, z: NaN } glMain.js:162:5
Object { x: NaN, y: 0, z: NaN } glMain.js:220:5
Object { x: NaN, y: 0, z: NaN } glMain.js:226:5
Array [ NaN, 0, NaN ] glMain.js:228:0
Array [ NaN, 0, NaN ] glMain.js:230:0
Object { x: -0.002365838535297038, y: 0, z: 0.0009121675219786463 }    glMain.js:162:5
```

To confirm that these values are indeed too small I uploaded the second photo first, and the console produced much more sensible values - leading me to believe there is something wrong with my code?

here is the particular function im using of the library linked to above:

```
function lonLatToVector3( lng, lat, out )
{
out = out || new THREE.Vector3();

//flips the Y axis
lat = PI / 2 - lat;

//distribute to sphere
out.set(
            Math.sin( lat ) * Math.sin( lng ),
            Math.cos( lat ),
            Math.sin( lat ) * Math.cos( lng )
);

return out;

}
```

I've uploaded the full version of the JS file and console output to my Git gist:

[glMain-V'lon_lat_to_cartesian-console](https://gist.github.com/3skimo/baffa6fa790befeaf840)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as i've looked over it many times and dont what to do

Comment: In your source - in line 162. You logging your result position. But why are you so sure in your `data`? Log  `data` before calling for  `lonLatToVector3(data.latitude, data.longitude);` Seems like you have now `data.longitude` member.

Comment: I did as you instructed and get: "Object { focalLength: 29, width: 3264, height: 2448, latitudeRef: "North latitude", latitude: 52.62939166666667, longitudeRef: "West longitude", longitude: 1.1289861111111112, altitudeRef: "Sea level", altitude: 68.04699738903395, rotationRef: "True direction", 1 more… }" the data is from photographs and i've tested many different ones, but unfortunately I still get these tiny values

Comment: can't get it. could you post your code to jsFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eskimo___/cfLewqet/1/ unfortunately it doesnt render that well, though im new to js fiddle so let me know if theres anything i can do to improve it

Comment: I've just removing the instance of the exif reader function to ascertain if having two complicates things in any way. Console out outputs much more sensible results: Object { x: 0.3000008265807652, y: 0.903979138959778, z: -0.30466575189278505 }

Comment: instead of: Object { x: -0.002365838535297038, y: 0, z: 0.0009121675219786463 }

Comment: which = Object { x: 0.3002374104342949, y: 0.9038698398763119, z: -0.3047569686449829 } (vector of 1st photo) - { x: 0.3000008265807652, y: 0.903979138959778, z: -0.30466575189278505 } (vector of 2nd photo). This happens on line 236 : "vectorDiff = placementPosition.sub(viewerPosition);" - i need to make sure this happens only once the vector has been converted